# Colour zero values in heatmap.2()

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I am using `gplots` and `Rcolorbrewer` to make a heatmap using the `heatmap2()` function.
My data has zeros denoting that no data is recorded in this samples. To create the heatmap, I want these zeros to be coloured white and the rest above in a three colour legend.

Here is the code so far:

```
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "red"))(n = 299)
col_breaks = c(seq(0.001,0.2,length=100), seq(0.3,0.4,length=100), seq(0.5,0.6,length=100))

library(gplots)
heatmap.2(deco.hmBB, main = "BCC at day 0 and day 10", margins = c(6,9), trace = "none", 
density.info = "none", dendrogram = "none", col = my_palette,  breaks =  col_breaks, 
Colv = "NA")
```

Comment: Maybe replace the zeros with NA

Comment: Thanks for he help, it worked in the end

Answer (score 0):

As commented, replace zeros with NAs like so:

```
deco.hmBB[deco.hmBB == 0] <- NA
```

Now rerun the heatmap, adding `na.color`.

```
heatmap.2(deco.hmBB, main = "BCC at day 0 and day 10", margins = c(6,9),
trace = "none", density.info = "none", dendrogram = "none", 
col = my_palette, breaks = col_breaks, Colv = "NA", na.color = "White")
```

Comment: I am having an issue now that seems to be a difficult one to solve by what I read on other posts. I now get the following message: Error in hclustfun(distr) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)